# How to get number value with leading zeros in LibreOffic Calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

How to get number value with leading zeros in LibreOffic Calc?

[`FORMAT` function](https://help.libreoffice.org/3.4/Basic/Format_Function_Runtime) does not want to work:

[image]

I need value, not just formatting.

Comment: The `Format` runtime function is for LibreOffice Basic macros.  It is not a spreadsheet function.

Comment: Why can't use one in another?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [TEXT](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#TEXT) function can add leading zeroes without formatting the cell.  It returns a string.

[image: leading zeroes]

Even though it is a string, it can still be treated as a number in other formulas. For example `=D2+1` gives 2016124.

Comment: What is the purpose of backslash? For me it worked without it?

Comment: The backslash was borrowed from @tohuwawohu's deleted answer.  According to https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Number_Format_Codes, it makes the character literal.  It does not seem necessary here.

Comment: The backslash makes mandatory to add at least one zero. E.g.: `=TEXT(123,"\000")` gives 0123 while `=TEXT(123,"000")` gives 123.

Answer (score 5):

**This answer is about formatting**

I'd like to add to tohuwawohu's answer that you can also just increase the "Leading zeroes" field within the "Format Cells" dialog. This might be easier for those who prefer to use the graphical interface and mouse only.

1. select cell, col/row or sheet;
2. right-click, select "Format Cells..." (or Menu Format -> Cells);
3. click on the up arrow in the "Leading zeroes" box as many times as
   needed: two for 01, three for 001 and so on.

P.S. I'm adding this as a separate answer because I don't have enough reputation to comment.

P.S. I gave this answer because I understood the sentence: "I need value, not just formatting." to mean something else from what you subsequently explained in a comment to tohuwawohu's answer. He consequently deleted his answer but I'm leaving mine because it has been upvoted and could be of some use even though it did not address your question in its true meaning.